# How does a disentangler disentangle a short ranged entangled (SRE) states in multi-scale entanglement renormalization ansatz (MERA) circuit?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, renormalization

I encounter a problem in understanding the role of disentanglers in Multi-scale entanglement renormalization ansatz (MERA). I do understand that without disentanglers, some short ranged entangled (SRE) modes will propagate to next RG level which is unwanted, therefore, we apply the "disentangler" to first disentangle the SRE states. However, I don't understand how the disentangler disentangles a SRE modes and how the SRE be removed. From [Vidal' paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0912.1651)(p.10), he said that the disentangler can turn an entangled state $ (1/ \sqrt{2}) | 1_r 1_s \rangle + |2_r 2_s \rangle $ to a product state $ | 1_r 1_s \rangle $. Could someone explain how this process actually work and how the entanglement be removed? Is there an explicit form of the disentangler for this problem?

Comment: No screenshots of text, please.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch, thank you for reminding me, I will delete the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know how you can create entanglement between two qubits with a CNOT gate? Invert this and you have the disentangler you talk about.

Specifically, if you apply a CNOT gate to $(\lvert1\rangle+\lvert2\rangle)\otimes\lvert1\rangle$, you get the state $\lvert1,1\rangle+\lvert2,2\rangle$ you talk about. Invert it, and you have disentanged said state.

If you want to end up with $\lvert1,1\rangle$, you still have to do a Hadamard transformation on the first qubit.

Comment: thank you for your  explicit example. I am not familiar with quantum information/circuit so I do not know an entangled pairs can be created using CNOT gate.